# Searching for options to refactor and simplify programming in IAR Embedded Workbench IDE

Tags: c, ide, refactoring, iar

I've been using eclipse until recently for java. I'm starting out with a embedded c project and there seems to be a lot of functionality missing in IAR Embedded Workbench IDE. I don't want to switch as projects I'm working on are made for this IDE and migrating would be quite a hassle.

Is there a way to enable refactoring and clicking to find declarations of variables etc. ?

Comment: You can import it in Eclipse with the IAR plugin and you all functionality of Eclipse IDE.

Comment: What about library dependencies from the micro controller and the IAR compiler?

Comment: You'll work with Eclipse as in IAR workbench.

Comment: I'll try this but I'm a bit skeptical, what about debugging?

Comment: BTW You can use Eclipse only to refactor your project and the return in IAR Workbench

Comment: Ok, seems like a good workaround, but doing it in IAR is not possible then?

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible. I know that there are plugins tu customize IAR Workbench, but I have no experience on that.

Comment: While IAR compiler is good, the IDE is only average, as they for embedded systems often are. I only use IDEs for compiling and debugging, and leave other tasks to other tools (Notepad++ for text editing, TortoiseHg for version control, etc.). That way I don't have to relearn everything every time I need to work on new platform.